# How to delete a tar file after I gzip it?

Tags: tar, gzip

I am creating a tar file and then I am gzipping the tar file. So I am getting a .tgz file and now I want to delete the previous tar file.

```
${gzipExe} -f --rsyncable $tarname.TAR --stdout >> $tarname.TGZ
```

Comment: Did you try rm or del?

Comment: I suggest zipping it at the same time you tar it (e.g, $ tar -cvzf filename.tar.gz)

Comment: @WhirlWind i would like to delete the tar file from the statement i use to gzip it.

Comment: @MJB  actually i could do that, but i need to use the tar.exe and gzip.exe for each of them. so I made both into different statements.

Comment: You can only do so if gzip has such an option.  I'm not aware it does, but you can check for your platform.

Comment: What system are you on?  On any system I've used, `gzip file` doesn't leave the original file.

Comment: @jemfinch i am working on windows xp...

Comment: @jemfinch @superstar Running GNU gzip from the command line without any options will delete the original file for you

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping you were using linux.  But I guess if you were, then you would not have asked the question.  My oversight.

Comment: @MJB The msys Windows port works the same as the Linux version. Other ports should work the same way.

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin: i am using -f and --rsynchable options for gzip

Comment: @superstar Are you redirecting standard in/standard out with `<` and `>` or are your just passing the filename to gzip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually zip the file at the same time by using the 'z' parameter with the tar command:

```
tar czvf allmyfiles.tar.gz *
```

The above command creates a new archive file called allmyfiles.tar.gz that contains all the files in the current folder, and zips it.

Otherwise, just delete the .tar file with the next command:

```
$rm $tarname.TAR
```

Note that .tar.gz is more commonly used than .tgz.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options. Assuming you need that `--rsyncable` option:

- Compress and tar in one step (without an intermediate tar file):

```
REM I think you are on Windows so...
set GZIP=--rsyncable
tar czf file.tar.gz files
```

- Pipe the output of tar into gzip (without an intermediate tar file)

```
tar c files | gzip --rsyncable > file.tar.gz
```

- Archive and compress in two steps.

```
tar -cf file.tar files
gzip -f --rsyncable file.tar
```

If you simply run `gzip file.tar` instead of `gzip --stdout file.tar > file.tar.gz` gzip will delete the tar file for you.

Also note that using `gzip --stdout file.tar >> file.tar.gz` as in your question will actually append the new gziped contents to file.tar.gz which is probably not what you want.

Comment: did you intend to make this post Community Wiki?

Comment: @quack I know that a post becomes community wiki after the 8th edit and I was unsatisfied with the 7th. So basically yes. I did it on purpose. Feel free to edit it further ;-)

Comment: i actually wasn't aware until recently that it was 8-edits-by-the-owner that made a question CW; i thought the threshold was higher.  just commented to make sure there wasn't a problem.  carry on!  :)